# Why am I getting the wrong parent node in my function?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the parent node of the button, which should be the `td` element but instead I am getting the `body` element. What is causing that? I want to use only  JavaScript, no jQuery.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text'></td>
            <td><button class='clk' onclick="g(this)">click me!</button></td>
        </tr>
        <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function g(c) {
                alert(c.parentNode.nodeName);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have invalid html not putting `<tr>` in `<table>`. Browser then rejects it and encounters `<td>` which has no valid parent and then encounters `<button>` which has no valid parent and ends up in `<body>`.

When you provide invalid html markup you get unexpected results.

Wrap your `<tr>` in `<table></table>` and can also be in `<tbody>`, `<thead>` or `<tfoot>` within `<table>`

Note that some tags and particularly table tags are very specific about what parent and children are allowed.

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/G8V8xBjIChV8f4vOZgfa?p=preview)**</kbd>